# How do i get my makefile to run matlab scripts

Tags: matlab, latex, makefile

I have a makefile that I use when writing latex documents, it automatically makes my .eps, .svg and .dia files into .pdf files. But i would like to automatically make it run a matlab script, that makes several .eps files that i can then make into .pdf files. It should however only run the matlab script if it has been changes since last time the .eps files where made as the makefile becomes very slow if it has to open and close matlab each time it runs. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What part are you having difficulty with? Is it executing Matlab from within the Makefile? Or is it formulating the rules such that the scripts are only run when the source has changed? Also: what flavor of Make are you using (and on what operating system)?

Answer (score 3):

You can run in your `Makefile`:

```
matlab -r "myfunction(myargs)"
```

Answer (score 2):

To follow on from @Oli's suggestion, you might consider

```
MATLAB := /path/to/bin/matlab

myFigure.eps : myPlot.m myData.mat
    $(MATLAB) -r "try, myPlot('myData.mat', 'myFigure.eps' ); catch, end, exit"
```

or similar.